# create a new view in google spreadsheet from horizontal to vertical

Tags: google-sheets

i have 2 tabs, in tab1 i have
column C: users ids
column D-K: months
under each month there are numbers referring to each and every user of column C
how can i create a new tab2 so that i have
column A contains user, column B contains the 1st month, column C contains the number linked to the first month
each row should have user, month, related number repeated for each month (8, from May to December)
in this file i added the month in a formula (in tab2)
but how to repeat it for each userid?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NzzbZW5XksqHt8zqEnbr6mhSs6SkIyatCsrdxcES59Y/edit?usp=sharing
thanks!

you can check the shared file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(rep_,'tab1'!C3:C18, grp_,'tab1'!D3:K18, months_,'tab1'!D2:K2,
     Σ,reduce(wraprows(,3,),sequence(counta(rep_)),lambda(a,c,{a;{wrapcols(index(rep_,c),columns(grp_),index(rep_,c)),tocol(months_),tocol(index(grp_,c))}})),
     filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks rockinfreakshow! it worked like charm!